# Ignoring NULL value columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query which looks something like this:

```
select 
tbl1a.col_id as col_id_1, tbl1a.prj_name as col_name_1,
tbl1b.col_id as col_id_2, tbl1b.prj_name as col_name_2,
tbl1c.col_id as col_id_3, tbl1c.prj_name as col_name_3
from [table1] tbl1a
left join [table1] tbl1b on tbl1a.col_id = tbl1b.col_pid
left join [table1] tbl1c on tbl1b.col_id = tbl1c.col_pid
```

This returns lots of rows ranging from

```
row 1
col_id_1 = col id 1 here
col_name_1 = col name 1 here
col_id_2 = col id 2 here
col_name_2 = col name 2 here
col_id_3 = col id 3 here
col_name_3 = col name 3 here

row 2
col_id_1 = col id 1 here
col_name_1 = col name 1 here
col_id_2 = col id 2 here
col_name_2 = col name 2 here
col_id_3 = null
col_name 3 = null

row 3
col_id_1 = col id 1 here
col_name_1 = col name 1 here
col_id_2 = null
col_name_2 = null
col_id_3 = null
col_name_3 = null
```

and so on.

I know how to get that info into a defined table, but don't know how to do it in the following form.  For all the rows, in this example, rows 1,2,3, I want to define a temp table:

```
declare @temp_tbl table (full_path varchar(255), path_id int)
insert into @temp_tbl (full_path, path_id)
select (something)
```

`@temp_tbl` should end up containing something like this:

```
row 1
full_path = col name 1 here\col name 2 here\col name 3 here\
path_id = col id 3 here

row 2
full_path = col name 1 here\col name 2 here\
path_id = col id 2 here

row 3
full_path = col name 1 here\
path_id = col id 1 here
```

Is it possible to do this without using a loop?  Or is a loop appropriate here?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted and received close votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ending select should get you the result that you want.  I spun up a table variable to simulate your "table1".  Maybe not the best way, but this will get the results you're asking for :)

```
declare @table table (
                        col_id_1 INT,
                        col_name_1 VARCHAR(30),
                        col_id_2 INT,
                        col_name_2 VARCHAR(30),
                        col_id_3 INT,
                        col_name_3 VARCHAR(30))
insert into @table (col_id_1, 
                    col_name_1, 
                    col_id_2, 
                    col_name_2, 
                    col_id_3, 
                    col_name_3)
values  (1, 'c1 name', 2, 'c2 name', 3, 'c3 name'),
        (1, 'c1 name', 2, 'c2 name', null, null),
        (1, 'c1 name', null, null, null, null)


DECLARE @temp_tbl TABLE (full_path VARCHAR(255), path_id INT)
INSERT INTO @temp_tbl (full_path, path_id)
SELECT (col_name_1 + '/' + col_name_2 + '/' + col_name_3 + '/'), col_id_3
FROM @TABLE WHERE col_id_3 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT (col_name_1 + '/' + col_name_2 + '/'), col_id_2
FROM @TABLE WHERE col_id_2 IS NOT NULL AND col_id_3 IS NULL
UNION
SELECT col_name_1 + '/', col_id_1
FROM @TABLE WHERE col_id_2 IS NULL AND col_id_3 IS NULL

SELECT *
FROM @temp_tbl
ORDER BY path_id DESC
```